# How is the following "at the risk of using a bad pun"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

One of the guys was telling the rest of us about his new girlfriend (whom we've met). In explaining why he liked her, he said, "At the risk of using a bad pun," (pause), "a lady swallows" (pause) "her pride."

That seemed straightforward enough to me. One thing he likes about this woman is that she "swallows her pride." Which seems like an important trait given that she is not the most pleasant person in the world, and apparently is prone to quarreling with him (and us).

What's confusing is the "bad pun" part. Is it something connected with "a lady swallows her pride?" Or could it be about the fact that she is so quarrelsome? And were those pauses "pregnant pauses?"

Comment: Is it in bad taste to say I think this question borders on being in bad taste?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I don't believe that the question was in bad taste "on its face" (and I was careful to word it as such). Yes, it may ALLUDE to bad taste. But the point of ELU is to clarify ambiguous statements that we hear every day. Put another way, I had a "hunch" that it was bad usage, but didn't know why until now. When T. Boone Pickens was castigated for asking an "ignorant" question, his answer was "I'd rather be ignorant TODAY than ignorant the rest of my life!"

Comment: It would be a pun if, after having an argument with her boyfriend, the woman gathered five or six animal crackers in the shape of lions into a group, turned to her boyfriend and said "Okay, I've decided to admit that I was wrong, and swallow my pride," and then consumed the animal crackers. Otherwise (as Erik Kowal notes), the boyfriend is dealing not in puns but in innuendo.

Comment: @SvenYargs: Your version is what I think was meant. Thanks for clearing this up.

Answer (score 4):

The only thing I can think of is that when your friend paused in his delivery, he was making an oblique reference to his girlfriend swallowing his semen during oral sex (though presumably that would represent the swallowing of *his* pride more than of *hers* :)

Failing that, there seems to be no basis for asserting the existence of a pun, bad or otherwise.

But it's really a case of *sexual innuendo*, not punning.

Comment: OK, maybe she does that in bed, and swallows her pride outside of it.

Comment: @TomAu - You may be right. You're in a much better position than me to judge that, as I don't have the — ahem — **benefit** of  her friendship.   ;)

Comment: I couldn't exactly ask my friend what he meant, which is why I asked it here.

Answer (score 3):

The "pun" that the speaker references is actually not a pun at all, but is more of double entendre. He is playing on the use of the word "swallows" to include a more vulgar usage in connection with oral sex which, in stereotypical polite society, is not something in which a "lady" engages.

Answer (score -3):

I don't see a pun. Like the previous answer, I understand what the guy likes about his new gf is that she "swallows" her pride. . . Since one cannot literally swallow pride, it is a "figure of speech," not a pun. And yes, it is a bad euphemism because of the adolescent innuendo. Questioner: Try swallowing your own pride dude and grow up!

Comment: The questioner was talking about what his *friend* said, not what *he* said.